# Replacing PHP ArrayObject

Tags: php, arrayobject

I have a PHP file where I am wondering if there is a way to replace ArrayObject with something else? I have the following:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <sizeof($compO); ++$i) {
        $cpO[] = self::equal_array($compO[$i]);
           I do a bunch of stuff here
    }

    protected static function equal_array($arr){
        $arrayObject = new ArrayObject($arr);
        return $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
     }
```

For some reason, the new ArrayObject call in equal_array() is giving me an error that indicates that ArrayObject is not in the namespace. Is there a way to replace the equal_array function with something equivalent or is there a way to correct the namespace problem? I thought ArrayObject was part of PHP so not sure why it isn't found in the namespace.

Comment: try `new \ArrayObject()`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
use ArrayObject;
```

after setting the namespace of your file.

Comment: this may have worked...I have a bit of testing to do but at least so far I don't get the same error so I am very hopeful. I just would've thought I wouldn't need to do that as I would have thought it was already part of PHP and so would've been included...guess not. THANKS!

Comment: Builtin classes are in the global namespace `\ArrayObject`